# Rest API usage addon for heroku

Tags: node.js

Do you know of any addon on Heroku that provides a report on the usage of API/Routes that are being called by end users?

I have tried searching heroku with different keywords but did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this package over here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics.

This would work in any NodeJS environment so it works even if you are not using Heroku.

If you are looking for a Heroku only solution, Just search for `"analytics"` in Heroku Elements: https://elements.heroku.com/search?q=analytics and you'll find a lot of results.

If you do want to put the burden on the server, you can just use Google Analytics on the client side. It is very strait forward to install and use. Just plug it into your website. However, this would not work for API routes and only for the web pages that the users visit.

Comment: Thanks Guys, searching analytics helped. 
I am using "Moesif API Analytics" and this is what was needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an herkou add-on, add your own logging.
If you want to be able to go back and look, use google analytics and do Events.